# AngularJS: Using JS functions inside directives - bad practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this part of code inside ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-show="parameter == 'MyTESTtext'">{{parameter}}</div>
```

where *parameter* is some $scope string variable ...

I wanted to see if its possible to check (inside ng-show for instance) whether *parameter* **contains** a substring.

You could do this with:

```
<div ng-show="parameter.indexOf('TEST') != -1">{{parameter}}</div>
```

which seems to be working; it displays every *parameter* that contains 'TEST' keyword.

I was wondering:

- is this a correct way of doing this within AngularJS app?
- Is it OK to use javascript built in functions like that?

**EDIT:**

*parameter* is actually formed like this: (and is thus not a $scope variable as I said above, sorry)

```
<div ng-repeat="(parameter,value) in oneOfMyScopeArrays">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you're dealing with strings in `ngRepeat` and not objects, there's no place to set flag to in your data elements. In this case I would advise using a custom directive. I do not agree with Darryl Snow's opinion that directive in this case is redundant. With directive (as it was the case with flag in controller) you can evaluate `parameter` once instead of doing so in every `$digest` cycle. Furthermore, if you decide to implement same functionality in other template, instead of copying the expression around, which is redundant, you'd reuse same directive. Here's a quick idea of such directive:

```
.directive('parameter', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $attrs.$observe('parameter', function(parameter) {
        if (parameter.indexOf('TEST') == -1) {
          $element.hide();
        } else {
          $element.text(parameter);
          $element.show();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<div parameter="{{parameter}}"></div>
```

This directive even sets up one watcher less per parameter comparing to your original solution, which is better performance wise. On the other hand, it disables two-way binding (parameter text is rendered once), so it won't work in case you want to edit `parameter` string in place.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Is it correct way? Technically yes, because it works. Is it OK? Not so much because of several reasons:

**Performance**. Everytime `$digest` loop runs (it might run quite a lot, depending on interactivity of application), it has to process every such expression. Therefore string `parameter.indexOf('TEST') != -1` has to be parsed and evaluated, which means calling `.indexOf` up to several times after each interaction, for example click on element with `ngClick` directive. Wouldn't it be more performant to test this assumption `parameter.indexOf('TEST') != -1` once in Controller and set a flag, e.g.

```
$scope.showParameter = parameter.indexOf('TEST') != -1
```

In template you would write

```
<div ng-show="showParameter">{{parameter}}</div>
```

**Model logic in template**. It's hard to tell the actual reasoning from your example when the parameter should be visible, but is it up to the template to have this logic? I think this belongs to controller, if not model to decide, that your view layer would be decoupled from making assumptions about how the model actually works.

Comment: I agree - performance can be an issue. The thing is I am displaying different data as to what the user clicks. So I am rendering this ng-repeat for different data (and thus parameter) for every users' click and would have to set flag every time as well.Is it still better to change ng-show expression in controller then?

Comment: Is your `value` in `ngRepeat` a string or an object?

Comment: the value is a string

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perfectly ok I think. You could write a separate directive of your own that does the same thing - it may look a bit tidier but it's ultimately redundant when angular comes with ng-show already built in, and it means a slight additional payload to the user. You could also do a $scope.$watch on `parameter` and set another scope variable for ng-show, but that just moves the mess from your view to your controller.

```
$scope.$watch('parameter', function(){
    if(parameter.indexOf('TEST') != -1)
        $scope.showit = true;
});
```

and then in the view:

```
<div ng-show="showit">{{parameter}}</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I edit my question: parameter is not a scope variable so I guess I cant just $watch it then right?